# Creating iCal Subscription Links from WordPress Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, calendar, google-calendar-api, custom-post-type, icalendar

I've created my own events calendar using a WordPress custom post type and I need to make the calendar subscribable to Google Calendar and the Mac OSX calendar app. The Mac calendar is working perfectly, but Google's having issues.

I used this website's script as a foundation to create my own script that generates my iCal file: http://www.noeltock.com/web-design/wordpress/how-to-ical-with-custom-post-types/

I've scoured through this site trying to make sure I had all the necessary fields: http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/

I've also compared my generated iCal file to the one generated by the WP plugin Events Calendar Pro.

When I click the Mac absolute link (using webcal instead of http), it launches the app and loads the events in the file just fine.

When I click the Google link (using /render?cid=feed), it opens a tab asking if I want to add the calendar. I click yes and then get hit with an error saying I don't have access to that calendar.

Here's an example of my generated iCal file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Site Name//NONSGML Events //EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Site Name
X-ORIGINAL-URL:Site URL
X-WR-CALDESC:Site Description

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20140401T070000
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20140401T230000
DTSTAMP:20140326T001707
CREATED:20140103T041301
LAST-MODIFIED:20140325T150531
SUMMARY:April Fool's Day
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:Blah blah blah
END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing? I've been fighting with this for two weeks and my client wants to launch his site. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting headers?

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/Calendar' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: inline; filename=calendar.ics' );
```

For Google you can build a query string link.  Here is how I'm doing it and it works fine.

```
$google => array(
                'label' => 'Google',
                'icon'  => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/common/ico_google.png',
                'url'   => 'http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&trp=false'
                    . '&text='    . $title
                    . '&details=' . $description
                    . '&dates='   . $date_start->format( $date_format )
                    . '/'         . $date_end->format( $date_format ),
            );

<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $google['url'] ) ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $google['url'] ) ?>" rel="external" target="_blank">
```

Comment: Yes, however the content-disposition I'm using is attachment. I tried switching it to inline, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference. Is it case-sensitive?

Comment: Actually you don't need to use an ical file with google.  Just build a query string.  See updated answer.